Possible issue with tcp_tw_recycle causing TCP connection failures
I am experiencing an issue where a Linux server sometimes does not respond to TCP connection requests with a SYN-ACK packet. I have a traffic capture showing a successful connection followed by a connection attempt that receives no response from the server, both initiated from the same client.
In the capture, I noticed that the tsval of the client in the first (successful) connection is 1447693633, while in the failed connection attempt, the client's tsval is significantly lower at 538289074. Additionally, only 46 seconds passed between the time the previous connection was closed and the failed connection was initiated, so the TIME-WAIT state should not have expired yet.
Afterward, the client tried again to open a connection with a tsval of 538306187, which is still smaller than 1447693633. However, as this connection attempt occurred 62 seconds after the first one closed, the TIME-WAIT state may have expired by then. I’m unsure about this though, as I’m unclear whether the TIME-WAIT timeout lasts 60 seconds or 120 seconds.
Could this issue be related to the tcp_tw_recycle option on the server? Is it possible that the server is dropping the client’s SYN packets because they have a timestamp smaller than the one stored by the kernel for this client?

References:

Coping with the TCP TIME-WAIT state on busy Linux servers
Why would a server not send a SYN/ACK packet in response to a SYN
packet

Thank you for your help.
